# NUnit Test Not Storing or Using Variable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, variables, datatable, nunit

Original code is as follows:

```
 [Test]
 public void TestCsvReader()
 {
     CustomUploadModel model = new CustomUploadModel();
     DataTable dt = (DataTable)PrivateTester.RunInstanceMethod(typeof (CustomUploadModel), "ParseCSV", model, new object[] {m_testFilesPath + FxTest, ',', 1});
 }
```

When I check my locals, the DataTable doesn't exist.  I've also tried instantiating with `DataTable dt = new DataTable`, but the table still doesn't exist.  I've checked `RunInstanceMethod` and it's working fine.  Any ideas as to what causes this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the DataTable doesn't exist"? Do you mean your `dt` variable is null after executing the assignment? Or do you mean the `dt` variable doesn't show up in the Locals window at all (which would be reasonable, since you're never using it and the compiler could optimize away the variable)?

Comment: The second one.  The compiler was optimizing it away- I hadn't thought of that.  Thanks.

Comment: It optimizes it away during debugging!?

Comment: Yes. It's not used so the compiler doesn't bother emitting the IL. Stuff an assert in there for number of rows expected, or some such. Anything the compiler can optimise out, it will.

Comment: @JoeWhite Would you be so kind as to answer the question, so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the compiler is optimizing away your variable.